# Spring integration upgrade issue. Unable to register MBean [bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.RouterFactoryBean#0'

Tags: spring-integration, mbeans

I have upgraded spring (no boot) application to java 17 and spring 6.1.3, also version of spring integrartion was upgraded from 4.1.2.RELEASE to 6.2.1. I have builded jar successfully, but when i have tried to run under tomcat 10 another application, that uses first one as i dependency in logs i found following exception:

```
    org.springframework.jmx.export.UnableToRegisterMBeanException: Unable to register MBean [bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.RouterFactoryBean#0'; defined in: 'class path resource [download_datafeed_flow.xml]'; from source: ''int:router''] with key 'org.springframework.integration.config.RouterFactoryBean#0'
        at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanNameOrInstance(MBeanExporter.java:641)
        at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.lambda$registerBeans$2(MBeanExporter.java:568)
        at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1421)
        at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeans(MBeanExporter.java:568)
        at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.afterSingletonsInstantiated(MBeanExporter.java:451)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:986)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:959)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:706)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:583)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:537)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:169)
        at jakarta.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:143)
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.init(HttpServlet.java:121)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:944)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:808)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4617)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4910)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:683)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:658)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:712)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1833)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:294)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:814)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:802)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:422)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:376)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:294)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:814)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:802)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:472)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1472)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1310)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1412)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:360)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:587)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:705)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:704)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)
    Caused by: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.springframework.integration.router:name=org.springframework.integration.config.RouterFactoryBean#0,type=MethodInvokingRouter
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Repository.java:436)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerWithRepository(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1865)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:960)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:895)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:320)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:523)
        at org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanRegistrationSupport.doRegister(MBeanRegistrationSupport.java:138)
        at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanInstance(MBeanExporter.java:695)
        at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanNameOrInstance(MBeanExporter.java:631)
        ... 61 more
```

in integration configs of my first app `<int:router>` occurs three times.
I have no idea what is the issue.

UPD: now, at least, i have an idea what is the issue about - issue happens because bean with name `org.springframework.integration.router:name=org.springframework.integration.config.RouterFactoryBean#0,type=MethodInvokingRouter`
is registered twice. Addition of unique id attr (`<int:router id="issueRouter"`) does not solve the issue.
Observing in debug i found that beans with following names are passing registration:

```
org.springframework.integration.router:name=org.springframework.integration.config.RouterFactoryBean#4,type=ExpressionEvaluatingRouter

org.springframework.integration.router:name=org.springframework.integration.config.RouterFactoryBean#1,type=ExpressionEvaluatingRouter
```

so, obviously there is some logic incrementing #n number in bean name (i do believe this why previous version of the application was built and deployed without any issue), but somehow it is not incrementing the number in my router-bean name in upgraded version.

Answer (score 1):

> Caused by: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.springframework.integration.router:name=org.springframework.integration.config.RouterFactoryBean#0,type=MethodInvokingRouter

The Tomcat is a single JVM and the whole JMX registry is shared. So, when you have beans with the same name they are going to clash with such an error.

One of the solution is to follow Microservices recipes and don't have several applications in the same JVM or just disable JMX for those applications: `spring.jmx.enabled = false`.

Or give those Spring Integration components unique ids.